# Replacing/joining names based on ID, and check and replace all names that have been changed based on ID

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have two different dataframes, with information about "Name" and "id"
Df1 is larger than df2.
I would like to "join" on ID, so that the brand name from df2 will be considered as correct in df1.
However, I would also want to find all the names that have been replaced in df1, and replace them with the relevant name from df2.
Sample:
df1

```
index    id         name
0        123        Del Monte
154047   124        Pokmon
171696   125        Pokmon
69264    126        Pokmon

df2
index   name     id
79376   Pokémon  124        
135487  Pokémon  125
```

result:

```
df1
index    id         name
0        123        Del Monte
154047   124        Pokémon
171696   125        Pokémon
69264    126        Pokémon
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with helper `Series` created by left join with [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
s = (df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left')
         .dropna(subset=['name_y'])
         .drop_duplicates(['name_x','name_y'])
         .set_index('name_x')['name_y'])
df1['name'] = df1['name'].map(s).fillna(df1['name'])
print (df1)
    index   id       name
0       0  123  Del Monte
1  154047  124    Pokémon
2  171696  125    Pokémon
3   69264  126    Pokémon
```